# Unable to install GeoPandas/GDAL

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas.

To achieve that I need to install the GDAL dependency.

I am neither able to intall geopandas nor able to install GDAL.

Environment Anaconda 4, Python 3.6

Methods I have tried:

1. pip intall appropriate library
2. conda install appropriate library
3. Downloaded suggested wheels from various thredas still failed
4. Tried to setup environements custom ones then also failed.

Comment: Can you show the commands that you used and the errors that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without any issue:

```sh
# create environment called geo and install python 3.6 and geo panda from conda-forge channel
conda create -n geo  -c conda-forge  python=3.6 geopandas
```

To use geopanda, activate the environment geo and all is well

```sh
conda activate geo
# test that geopanda imports okay
python -c "import geopanda"
```

If no error the geopanda was correctly install in your geo environment

If you need other packages to be install in your geo conda environment, then add them with

```sh
conda install -n geo PACKAGENAME PACKAGE2
```

If you are using Spyder, you need to have spyder in your environment too:

```sh
conda install -n geo spyder
conda activate geo
spyder
```

Now your spyder has access to all packages in geo environment. If you do not wish to install spyder in this environment and use spyder in base environment instead, you can do

```sh
# install spyder kernel
 conda install -n geo spyder-kernels

# get the path to geo python executable and copy the path
conda activate geo
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"

# deactivate geo
conda deactivate 

# this returns you to base environment 
# open spyder from base

spyder
```

In spyder GUI, head to Tool > Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following interpreter and paste the geo environment python executable path.

I believe there is an icon at the lower right of spyder that allows you to toggle between environments. But not sure if it is still there as last time I used spyder was 2016.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-fc7d1d298f0c>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas

  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\geopandas\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pyproj import _datadir

ImportError: cannot import name '_datadir'

Comment: It did install but unable to access it from spyder

Comment: I tried still not working but I got it working in the Jupyter notebook

Comment: FYI Spyder error:
  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pyproj import _datadir

ImportError: cannot import name '_datadir'

Comment: The error show that you are using a wrong environment

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-fc7d1d298f0c>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas
  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\geopandas\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
  File "C:\Users\adity\anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pyproj import _datadir

ImportError: cannot import name '_datadir '

Comment: I have copy pasted as it is